# Number of Uses for Visual Studio 2019 Professional

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I am buying a Visual Studio 2019 Professional Subscription.  How many uses does it have or if it is unlimited how many concurrent computers can have it installed?

Comment: VS is a user based license, not machine based

Comment: so as long as you are logged into your account, the license is active?

Comment: its not a floating license...it's just per user...you are the user...someone else cannot login when you log out